# How to change the look of folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop-customization, public-folders

Probably a fairly simple, basic question here:  how do I change the way these folders look, but still allow them to be dynamic and show their contents?

[image: Folders]

I'm looking for a PC-wide solution, NOT FOLDER SPECIFIC.

[edit] I managed to get further using a program called "Customizer god"

I managed to replace the front and back image of the folder:

imgur.com/a/KBPhU

However the "middle part" or the white square frame remains and I can't find it's resource location, and therefore can't get it to look exactly how I look.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible.. You can change the whole icon image and you can also choose which images should be displayed on the icon image, but you can't change the look of your folders while keeping the images visible like that.

Comment: Well, sorry, that's just flat out incorrect.

I managed to get this far (replacing the front and back image):

http://imgur.com/a/KBPhU

However the "middle part" the white square frame I can't find it's resource location, and therefore can't get it to look exactly how I look, however, it is more than possible (and I've used themes that have achieved this)

Comment: You have proven me wrong, nice job. I didn't think it would be possible. Why don't you go ahead and write it as an answer?

Comment: because it's not an answer, it doesn't fully resolve the issue.